# What's the best way to classify time text data?

Tags: r, machine-learning, text-classification

This is a straight-forward question:

I have time text data that looks like the following:

110
120+
50 minutes
50 Minutes
35-40
30
1 hour and a half 
1 hour 20 Minutes

What's the best way to clean this data so that I can analyze it? Is this a job for machine learning? If so, what are the librarys/tools that would help me most in this situation?

One thought is using gsub:

"as.numeric(gsub("([0-9]+).*$", "\1", Timedata))" but that over-simplifies the data.

I would like the data to look like this after cleaning:

110
120
50
50
37.5
30
90
80

Comment: How many observations in your data?

Comment: Around ~500 records or so

Comment: If your examples show the full extent of erroneous values, then I might simply (1) flag values that include the word "minutes" and then remove the word "minutes" with `sub`. Then (2) flag values that longer than, say, four characters and recode those with `ifelse` and `str_detect` or manually.

Comment: you should build a dictionary from those numbers and assign numerical representations each of those numbers for the words possible has types use Levenshtein distance to approximate closest representation in dictionary.

https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/fuzzy-string-python

Comment: Write if conditions with regular expression checking the format of string should do the work.

Answer (score 0):

Tough to say where this will break, but maybe it gives you some ideas:

```r
library(tidyverse)

times <- c("110", "120+", "50 minutes", "50 Minutes", 
           "35-40", "30", "1 hour and a half", "1 hour 20 Minutes")

times %>%
  str_replace("..hour", "60") %>%
  str_replace("half", "30") %>%
  str_split("\\-") %>%
  map(~ ifelse(length(.) > 1, mean(as.numeric(.)), .)) %>%
  map(~ ifelse(is.character(.), str_extract_all(., "[[:digit:]]+"), .)) %>%
  flatten() %>%
  map_dbl(~ ifelse(is.character(.), sum(as.numeric(.)), .))
#> [1] 110.0 120.0  50.0  50.0  37.5  30.0  90.0  80.0
```